# Python vs Ruby: Is y greater than x and less than z?

Tags: ruby

Is there a less verbose way to compare three integer values in Ruby?

For example, in Python the following return True:

```
x = 2
y = 3
z = 4
x < y < z
```

With the same variable bindings in Ruby the following will both return true:

```
x < y && y < z
x.send(:<, y) && y.send(:<, z)
```

but this:

```
x < y < z
```

returns NoMethodError:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for true:TrueClass
```

I presume this is because the first comparison of `x < y` evaluates to `true` and the error is raised from the resulting `TrueClass.instance < z`? Is there a way in Ruby to compare three integer values without the use of &&?

Thank you.

Comment: While you can do it, one of Ruby's code-writing tenets is to avoid overly terse expressions when there is a more readable while still efficient way of doing it. Ruby isn't old-style C or Perl, where they considered it manly to write tersely. `x < y && y < z` is very idiomatic, as are Cary's solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
(x+1...z).cover? y
```

or (my preference)

```
(x+1..z-1).cover? y
```

Because `x`, `y` and `z` are numeric, this is the same as

```
(x+1..z-1).include? y
```

See [Range#cover?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) and [Range#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F).

Comment: I'd probably use `(x + 1 .. z - 1) === y` but that's just how I think of it.